# Can I use a variable to set a specific namespace in perl

Tags: perl

I know you can do

```
package Foo {
    # do stuff
}
```

but I don't think I can do

```
my $namespace = 'Foo';

package $namespace {
    # do stuff
}
```

so is there a way to set a block to "be" in a given namespace, with the namespace defined via a variable?

Or - to be precise - is [namespace::local](https://metacpan.org/pod/namespace::local) the simplest way?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: You can do that with string `eval`, but you probably shouldn't. It seems you've been doing really messy stuff recently. If this is for production code I strongly recommend to rethink your approach. Just because this might be possible isn't a reason it should be done.

Comment: @simbabque - thanks. I imagine that you''ve looked at my recent question, and "really messy" sounds almost like a compliment. I'm trying to get Mojo::Template to allow using at least some of the Mojolicious::Plugin::DefaultHelpers (or clones thereof) without going through Mojolicious - with "layout" as a priority See an old question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230849/

Comment: This is interesting. I don't have enough time to dive into it too deeply, but it sounds like a really odd but fascinating thing to do. I imagine if you take this to the mojo IRC channel they'll be rather confused about why you'd want to do it. I personally would like to have a more business value driven conversation questioning your motives for doing this on top of the actual technical conversation, but here isn't the place for that conversation. It's very easy to see an X-Y problem here without knowing all the variables. (I've not looked as deeply as I'd like to have a qualified opinion).

Comment: namespace::local doesn't do what you ask

Comment: Another [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). Please seek help with the actual problem you are having, not with these purported solutions to that problem. At the very least, be clearer in your questions. This is the second time in a few days you've posted questions that amount to "I want to do what this not-code does." Well, not-code doesn't do anything but throw an error when you treat it as code, so you're forcing us to guess what your question is since you didn't state it.

Comment: @ikegami - I see your point, am totally grateful for the feednack, and partially agree. I had started off by thinking of the broad question, but ended up trying to whittle it down to a more specific something. I've seen broad questions ("How do I enable use of Mojolicious helpers in Mojo::Template" comes to my mind as a viable alternative to my XY's) criticized as too vague, or left without answer. Also more specific questions from other people often seemed more useful to me as someone that googles later. Still: I'm totally open to constructive criticism (which yours is)

Comment: @simbabque - my business goal is: (a) to be able to use Mojo::Template without a Mojolicious server running (b) with all the helpers that would make sense in the context (c) to - for example - generate static output. This is possible for example in Template::Toolkit, but I would like to spare myself the effort of (re)learning the syntax of another templating system. I've made some progress - and so far it turns out not to feel so odd - at least IMHO. I'd be grateful for input on how to share back - after all I wouldn't have managed it without Ikegami's help

Comment: @simone the mojo IRC channel or at least mojolicious tag would be a great place to discuss your overall problem, my first suggestion would be "use the renderer of a dummy Mojolicious app".

Comment: @simone Mojolicious is a very modular system, you do not need to run a server to use an application.

Comment: Re "*I've seen broad questions  criticized as too vague*", There's no denying it's not a easy task, but big-picture questions can still be specific. Your goal is to minimize the cost for us to help you. Clarity is key, but you gotta realize we may not be familiar with the specifics either. So providing a test harness could be a great help, for example. ("What would I need to add to the following code to get it to print `ok`"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, to do this, you'd need to recompile the code.

So, given

```
my $foo = sub {
    # code here
};
```

Do:

```
my $newfoo = eval "package $package; sub " . B::Deparse->new->coderef2text($foo);
```

Comment: Note: That this can fail (compiled differently or not at all) if the recompilation occurs in a different lexical context than the original.

Answer (score 0):

No, code evaluated at run time can't set the package used to compile the same code. It's simply too late. You would have to defer the compilation of the code to be affected (e.g. by using `eval EXPR`, `do EXPR` or `require`).

(namespace::local does not do that.)